# How to include Perl into shtml files

Tags: html, perl, cgi, shtml

Hi I am trying to include a perl script within my shtml file. Unfortunately when I do my script doesnt seem to run but instead it just displays the content of the script.

The code I am using is as follows:

test.shtml:

```
<html>
<title> business home page </title>
<body>
</br>
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" --> 
<br />
<!--#include virtual="hello.pl"-->
</body>
</html>
```

hello.pl:

```
#!C:/Sun/WebServer6.1/bin/https/perl/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

print "Hello World!";
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Incase you all wanted to know the server I am using is Sun One WebServer 6.1 (OS = Windows XP). Thanks for your responses!

Comment: Are you trying to do "web programming circa 2003" for a particular reason?

Comment: This should be on serverfault.com, and has been answered before -- you need to ensure your server is properly set up to handle server-side includes and execute CGIs.

Comment: @Chad...Not really sure what you mean by that.
@Ether  I have a bad feeling it is that, but I can't find any good places to find out how to configure it for windows. I tried following the documents SUN provided to my best knowledge.

Comment: Ether means that there are lots of good toolkits out there for using perl to make webpages that don't require server side includes, including [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/), [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/), [Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/), or even the venerable [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *de facto* standard SSI directive for executing dynamic content within an SSI page is

```
<!--#exec cgi="hello.pl"-->
```

That works with Apache `mod_include` and at least a few other web servers that support SSI. No idea if it will work on your platform, but give it a shot.

Comment: i've given that a try seems to be giving me an error occured while processing this directive/

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the first print statement in your Perl program, which sets the content-type header.  That's not a useful thing to do in the body of an HTML page, which is where your SSI is located.

SSI is a rather quaint technology these days, even if it is occasionally useful, so if you are serious about learning web programming then this is not an area where you should spend much time.

Comment: Hey thanks for you response. No I am actually not learning this at all. It sort of like the tools I am givin to work with, so I have to try and make hte best of them. Dont have a choice.